# Where the 'Kahler' condition is used in the Kodaira Embedding theorem?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In the Griffiths and Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry, p.181, he states Kodaira Embedding theorem as follows :

**Kodaira embedding theorem (Ver.1)**. Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold and $L \to M$ a positive line bundle. Then there exits $k_0$ such that for $k \ge k_0$, the map $\iota_{L^k} : M \to  \mathbb{P}^N$ is well-defined and is an embedding of $M$ ; i.e., $L$ is ample (?).

On the other hand, in the Huybrechts's Complex geometry book he states Kodaira embedding theorem as follows :

**Kodaira embedding theorem (Ver.2).** Let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold. A line bundle $L$ on $X$ is positive if and only if $L$ is ample. In this case, the manifold $X$ is projective.

Where the Kahler condition is used? I found that in the Huybrechts's proof of the theorem, he used the Kodaira vanishing theorem ( Proposition 5.2.2.) which is stated as follows :

**Proposition 5.2.2 ( Kodaira Vanishing )** Let $L$ be a positive line bundle on a compact Kahler manifold $X$. Then $ H^q(X, \Omega_X^{p} \otimes L)=0$ for $p+q >n$.

Note that here the 'Kahler' condition is attached. But in the Griffiths's Proof (p. 190), he used other version of Kodaira-Nakano Vanishing theorem ( p.154) which is stated as follows :

**Kodaira-Nakano Vanishing Theorem.** If $L\to M$ is a positive line bundle, then $H^q(M, \Omega^p(L))=0$ for $p+q >n$.

A priori, it seems that in this theorem the condition Kahler is not attached but in Griffith's book p.148 he assumes that $M$ is a compact Kahler manifold. So there is a still possibiltiy of usage of the condition Kahler in the proof of Kodaira embedding theorem.

**C.f.** I am studying with next pdf note : [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/pdf/notes/complex-manifolds.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ecschnell/pdf/notes/complex-manifolds.pdf) In p.95 of the note, Corollary 31.7, he states Kodaira vanishing theorem same as the Proposition 5.2.2. above without imposing the condition 'Kahler'.

**Q.** It's really true that the condition 'Kahler' is redundant in the above Kodaira Vanishing theorem (Proposition 5.2.2)? If 'Kahler' condition is deleted, then the Proposition 5.2.2 is false ?

And at p.96, theorem 32.3 in the note, he states Kodaira embedding theorem similar as the Griffith's Kodaira theorem (Ver.1.) without imposing the condition 'Kahler'.

And then, in his note p. 103, first paragraph after Class 35, he mentioned that "What we have shown is : a line bundle $L$ on a compact Kahler manifold $M$ is positive if and only if $L$ is ample", same as the Kodaira embedding theorem (Ver.2) above.

Where the Kahler condition is used? What is problem? Is there a point that I missed?

**EDIT** : Through discussion with Arctic Char, I think that reason of addition of the adjective 'Kahler' in the statement of Kodaira embedding theroem of Huybrechts's version is, to emphasize that $X$ is Kahler with respect to the Kahler metric whose existence is guaranteed by the existence of positive line bundle.

And..I don't understand why such existence of Kahler metric from existence of positive line bundle is true ; here by positivity of line bundle, we adopt definition of Huybrechts's : A line bundle $L$ is called positive if its first Chern class $c_1(L) \in H^2(X, \mathbb{R})$ can be represented by a  closed positive real $(1,1)$-form. Here the positivity of a real $(1,1)$-form is defined as follows ( Huybrechts's book p.188, Definition 4.3.14 ).

**Definition 4.3.14.** A real $(1,1)$-form $\alpha$ is called (semi-)positive if for all holomorphic tangent vectors $0 \neq v \in T^{1,0}X$ one has
$$ -i \alpha(v,\bar{v}) >0  (\operatorname{resp.} \ge )$$

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quoting from the start of Class 31 in the note:

> Definition 31.1. A holomorphic line bundle $L \to M$ is called positive if its first Chern class $c_1(L)$ can be represented by a closed $(1, 1)$-form $\Omega$ whose associated Hermitian form is positive definite.

$\cdots$ (skipping several lines)

> Of course, such a form $\Omega$ is the associated $(1, 1)$-form of a Hermitian metric on $M$, and since $d\Omega = 0$, this metric is Kahler. In particular, if there exists a positive line bundle on $M$, then $M$ is necessarily a Kahler manifold.

So, the mere existence of a positive line bundle on $M$ already implies the existence of a Kahler metric.

Comment: O.K. Thanks for investigating my note and pointing out. I understand your intention as, if we accept definition 'positive' as in the note, then the condition Kahler is redundant in the Kodaira embedding theorem. True? And perhaps.. is there a possibility of difference between definition of positivity in the note and that of the Huybrechts's, so that in the Huybrechts's version of embedding theorem, 'Kahler' is necessary? Uhm, Huybrechts's version of positivity of line bundle is strictly weaker than that of the note?

Comment: I don't have the book by Huybrecht next to me. Is he using a different definition? @Plantation

Comment: O.K. In the Huybrecht's book, he defines that a line bundle $L$ is positive if its first chern class $c_1(L) \in H^{2}(X,\mathbb{R})$ can be represented by a closed positive real $(1,1)$-form. Here $(1,1)$-form means as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_form. An in his book p.239 he argues that a line bundle $L$ is positive if and only if it admits an hermitian sturcture such that the curvature of the induced Chern connection is positive.

Comment: Here positivity of curvature is defined as follows : Let $(E,h)$ be an hermitian vector bundle over a complex manifold $X$ and let $\nabla$ he an hermitian connection that satisfies $F_{\nabla} \in \mathcal{A}^{1,1}(X, \operatorname{End}(E))).$ Then $F_{\nabla}$ is positive if for any nonzero $s\in E$ one has $h(F_{\nabla}(s), s)(v, \bar{v})>0 $ for all non-trivial holomorphic tangent vectors $v$. I think that I am begginer for terminologies in complex geometry and so please understanding~

Comment: The question is much simpler than you describe and has not much to do with Chern classes and curvatures: Do you understand why if a complex manifold $M$ admits a closed positive $(1,1)$ form, then $M$ is Kahler? @Plantation

Comment: Yes, I wonder! I want to make such issue sure. Previously, let me rearrange our argument triggered from my question. It seems that there are two versions of definition of positivity of line bundle $L$ on $M$. First, in my note, $L$ is positive iff  there is a closed (1,1)-form $\Omega$ such that $c_1(L) = [ \Omega]$ and $h_{\Omega}$ ( associated Hermitian form ; what's exact meaning of this terminology? ) is positive definite. Second, in Huybrecht's book, $L$ is positive iff there is a closed positive real (1,1)-form $\Omega$ such that $c_1(L) = [ \Omega]$.

Comment: My question is, the first version of positivity implies the second ? ; i.e. , being $h_{\Omega}$ is positive definite( In fact, I don't know also what this terminology exactly means ) implies that $\Omega$ is positive real form? Or..perhaps, these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Anyway, why your claim - $M$ is Kahler if there exists closed positive real $(1,1)$-form - is true?

Comment: Because that's the definition of a Kähler form.